How do I build my unity project if I need to use UnityEditor.Animations?
Error
Assets\Scripts\Animatronic AI\Freddy.cs(2,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Animations' does not exist in the namespace 'UnityEditor' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

I have animations in my game, and I cannot build my game due to this line
using UnityEditor.Animations;

I replaced each
using UnityEditor.Animations;
with
#if UNITY_EDITOR
using UnityEditor.Animations;
#endif

however it's still saying
Assets\Scripts\Animatronic AI\Freddy.cs(23,12): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'AnimatorController' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

If I can't use AnimatorControllers, my game won't work. How do I fix this and build with the Animator Controllers?

You cannot use unity editor in built games, you just cant, they dont let you

So how do I build the game if I need to use animations on my objects?

using animations on objects doesnt need the unityeditor.animations.. so the question becomes what exactly are you doing?

public AnimatorController MenuPose; <---- I'm using these in my code

but why? what are you doing that you need to change the controller?

Please post your full code example ... there is no way you can use editor only tools in a build ... there is a reason why this is in a dedicated assembly and namespace ;) For telling you how to do things we need to know what exactly you are trying to do in the first place

put your code inside here
#if UNITY_EDITOR

public AnimatorController MenuPose;

#endif


Without seeing your actual use case it is a bit hard to tell you what to do.
In general: There is no way you can use UnityEditor things in a build. These things are supposed to exist and be used only within the Unity Editor itself and are stripped of (or better simply not included) in a build. There is a reason why these live in their own assembly and namespace.

The straight forward solution is probably: You simply rather wanted to

either use the more generic RuntimeAnimatorController instead which provides you access to the according AnimationClips.

or you actually wanted to go through the Animator which provides most of the information stored in the AnimatorController as well as the current states etc.



If you only have to access the controller in the editor - For example to do automatic things in OnValidate you can wrap it using the pre-processors
#if UNITY_EDITOR
// NOT only the namespace using but ANY code block that touches it!
#endif

It is not enough to only wrap the using statement, you will have to wrap ANY CODE BLOCK that is using the namespace or variables of a type from that namespace etc. These pre-processors are basically telling the compiler that these things shall be ignored when building - they won't exist at all in a build.
So if your intend was indeed to still access it in a build - no this will not be a solution! And actually there is none, except implementing a complete own animation system which would allow that.

I already answered my own question why are people still answering lmao. Also, I literally just had to do the if unity editor thing. It fixed it all

@Coco because your answer doesn't make much sense tbh ... this alone will still yield the same issue for any place where code is touching your field ...

Maybe what You are looking for is Animation component which is inside UnityEngine namespace.
